# Is there no way to install the latest stable MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, mariadb

The mariadb repository [contains only the beta 10.5 version](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=focal--ubuntu_focal&mirror=ossplanet&version=10.5) for 20.04 LTS and in the official ubuntu repository, [there is only the old stable 10.3 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mariadb-server). Is there no way to install the current stable 10.4 version for the latest ubuntu?

Comment: --> `docker run mariadb`